# почему переменная q = True меняет свой индекс в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
x = []
q = True
w = True
e = True

x.append(q)
x.append(w)
x.append(e)

print(x)

x[q] = False

print(x)
```

Comment: ``x[q] = False`` это ``x[True] = False``. Что ты хочешь сделать таким странным действием? Оно делает не то, что ты думаешь.

Comment: ^ ага. А x[False] = False поменяет 0-й элемент списка, потому что bool приводится к целым как 1 и 0

Comment: И если говорить правильно, то в списке нет переменной q. Там есть значение True. А переменная q со списком никак не связана.

Answer (score 2):

`True == 1`, поэтому при `q = True` вы меняете значение `x[1]`

Comment: а как тогда обращаться к элементу списка по значению в этом случае?

Comment: @kirich что вы подразумеваете под обращением к элементу списка по значению? Если нужно определить индекс значения (первого), можно использовать `x.index(True)`, но вам вернет индекс 0.

Comment: все понял, спасибо!)